# Optaplanner VRP, support multiple fuel consumption values based on vehicle type?

Tags: optaplanner

I have a VRP in which I would like to include fuel consumption as soft constraint and that it is different between vehicles based on type. So I would want the engine to select the vehicles with the least fuel consumption.

I thought about adding a multiplier to the vehicle type so that it is multiplied with distance as soft constraint, is it possible? and would it affect the result negatively?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible.

You distances can be in km. Then your score rule just multiplies each `distance` (= km) driven by a vehicle by that vehicle's `vehicle.getCostPerKm()`.

You can even also keep track of driving time in seconds for each distance and build one big weighted function:

```
addSoft(..., - ($distanceInKm * $vehicle.getCostPerKm() + $distanceInSeconds * $vehicle.getDriverWagePerSecond()));
```